# Modify a db_table type table of a db

Tags: abap

I created a database table with ID, firstname, lastname.
I created following program:

```
data: db_table type table of ztabletest. "Create my db data
select * from z6148tabletest into table db_table. "Fill my db data
data: modifiedLine type z6148tabletest. "Create my new line

modifiedLine-firstname = 'hey'.
modifiedLine-lastname = 'test'.
```

Now I want to modify the line in my db table index 2.

So I'm trying to do something like:

```
modify ztabletest from table db_table values modifiedLine at index 2.
```

I don't understand the logic for modifying.

To insert something I just do:

```
insert INTO ztabletest VALUES modifiedLine.
```

So here the logic is simple because I add in my table the values.
Can you explain me the logic to modify a line ?

Comment: Read the ABAP documentation and its examples: [MODIFY - Dbtab](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapmodify_dbtab.htm), [UPDATE](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapupdate.htm).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A database table has no "index". The order of the table rows is unspecified. When you do a `SELECT` without an `ORDER BY`, then the database can give you the row in whatever order it feels like. Most SQL databases tend to always give you the same order, but that's for *their* convenience, not for yours. Especially SAP HANA tends to be very moody in this regard.

But what database tables do have is a primary key. The primary key can be thought of as an unique identifier of each table row. So when you make the primary key a number, you can simulate an index pretty well. I assume that this is the purpose of the field "ID" in your databse column and that you therefore marked it as "key" when you defined your database.

---

[INSERT](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapinsert_dbtab.htm) adds a new line when no line with the same key values exists. When there already is one, it fails with sy-subrc = 4.

```
modifiedLine-id = 2.
INSERT ztabletest FROM modifiedLine.
```

[UPDATE](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapupdate.htm) changes an existing table line with the same key values. When no line with these primary key values exists in the table, it fails with sy-subrc = 4.

```
modifiedLine-id = 2.
UPDATE ztabletest FROM modifiedLine.
```

or alternative the more "traditional SQL" like syntax with `SET` and `WHERE`:

```
UPDATE ztabletest 
  SET firstname = 'hey'
      lastname = 'test'
  WHERE id = 2
```

[MODIFY](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapmodify_dbtab.htm) is the combination of INSERT and UPDATE (also known as an "upsert"). It checks if the line is already there. When it's there, it modifies the line. When it isn't, it inserts it.

```
modifiedLine-id = 2.
MODIFY ztabletest FROM modifiedLine.
```

Which is basically a shorthand for:

```
modifiedLine-id = 2.
UPDATE ztabletest FROM modifiedLine.
IF sy-subrc = 4.
    INSERT ztabletest FROM modifiedLine.
ENDIF.
```